# HTML5 valide re-entered values

Tags: html, forms, pattern-matching, validation

I have just used the HTML5 pattern attribute for the first time on a registration form client-side validation. It is working well and I plan to use it for live code.

In my registration form I have a `re-enter password` input field.

As I think re-enter values is used so often I was wondering: does exist some fancy HTML5 mechanism to check if a re-entered value matches the first entered value. Or will I still have to do that in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

HTML5 introduces an [`<output>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/output) element that is supposed to represent the outcome of some calculation (such as comparing two values). You can use its `for` attribute to associate it with the inputs on the page that affect its outcome. Here's the problem, though:

- You still need JavaScript to actually carry out the calculation.
- Firefox's rendering engine (Gecko) allows you to specify validity constraints and error messages for `<output>` [(see this page from the Mozilla documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Forms_in_HTML), but other rendering engines may not (and probably don't).
- HTML5 form validation (and HTML5 features in generally) are not supported on many very commonly-used browsers. For example, [anyone visiting your site using Internet Explorer < 10 or using most mobile browsers won't be able to use the form validation.](http://caniuse.com/form-validation)

If you want to provide instant validation feedback, your best bet is to use JavaScript, being sure that you validate the data again on the server.